# Tabbed Activity in Kotlin (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, tabs, kotlin

I am newbie on Kotlin, recently moved from Java, In java I used

```
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Tab1Contact tab1 = new Tab1Contact();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Tab2Contact tab2 = new Tab2Contact();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                Tab3Contact tab3 = new Tab3Contact();
                return tab3;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

for tabbed activity. I create 3 different classes for different tabs to organize data. In Kotlin I am unable to do so, I have tried

```
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
        when (position) {
            0 -> {
                val tab1 = TabOne()
                return tab1 as Fragment
            }
            1 -> {
                val tab2 = TabTwo()
                return tab2 as Fragment
            }
            2 -> {
                val tab3 = TabThree()
                return tab3 as Fragment
            }
        }
        return null
    }
```

> but app crashes, if i simply return tab1 then again Error occuses,
>   "Required Fragment Found TabOne"

Comment: "Required Fragment Found TabOne" ->  TabOne, TabTwo, TabThree must be extends Fragment. Like `class TabOne: Fragment() { .. }`

Comment: @pRaNaY already extended `class TabOne : Fragment()` but maybe there is another issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using

```
class TabOne : android.support.v4.app.Fragment() { }
```

instead of

```
class TabOne : android.app.Fragment() { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend your tab classes to fragment.
Make sure you need to import backward
compatibility

```
import android.support.v4.app.*
    class TabOne: Fragment() {
         // Implementations 
    }
```

Do for all class then try

Comment: All tabs classes are like 
`class TabOne : Fragment() {
}`
but still this happens

Comment: well the problem is solved by extending from `TabOne : android.support.v4.app.Fragment()`

Comment: Cool you was not importing Fragments  with backward compatibility